# Permissions for sqlite db stored outside the document root

Tags: php, sqlite

What permissions should I give a sqlite db file that I'm storing outside of the document root and which needs to be accessible by php scripts?

- should the file be owned by the webserver(lighttpd) user?
  or
- should I chmod it to give o+rw perms? (this doesn't seem like a good idea)

Background:

- I'm creating a php web application that *must* use an sqlite db.
- I have decided to store the db file outside of the document root so that it is not publicly accessible.
- The file needs to be readable and writable by the php scripts.

I'm pretty new to sqlite so any best practice tips on storing/permissions would be highly appreciated.